# How to add & link a second activity in actionbar compat in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using actionbar compat in my application first time.  I want to add another activity to the application.  When i press a SETTINGS from actionbar, i like to start the second activity.

How is possible ?

codes for my application as follows

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity( new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivity.class));

            break;
        }
    return true;
}

}
```

[image]
mainactivity image

Secondactivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

 }
```

[image]
secondactivity image

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityToStart.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

on the position where you pop up a Toast.

Comment: I added the second activity... but now shown not like main activity... see the updated question

Comment: YOu mean that you don't have an ActionBar there? Why have you declared the SecondActivity as Activity, and not as ActionBarActivity? You have to do the same in the SecondActivity if you want to provide an ActionBar there.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'app' instead of 'android' namespace prefix for 'actionLayout' attribute fixed it for me.
So, basically, use

```
app:actionLayout="@layout/yourLayout"
```

instead of

```
android:actionLayout="@layout/yourLayout"
```

I am assuming you are using app_compat library to get the theming engine.